# Activity Indicator doesn't work in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, activity-indicator

I am trying to show a simple activity indicator when my view controller loads until a segue is performed. I want to start the activity indicator on `viewDidLoad` but I have had no luck so far.

This is the code I was trying to use:

```
import UIKit

class LoadingScreen: UIViewController {
//Activity indicator view
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //start animating
        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
}
}
```

I get an error: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` which I assume means there's a problem with the code I'm using.

I then stop it after a function called delay:

```
delay(2.5) {

            self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your IBOutlet is connected? And it would be better if you'd include the full error message you're receiving.

Comment: @0x7fffffff I was pretty sure it was connected but of course upon re doing it, it was fixed. Would you happen to know how I could stop it when a segue is performed?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the IBOutlet is working correctly (as mentioned in your comment above). You probably want to `stopAnimating` your `activityIndicatorView` within the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // You might not need the if statement
    if (segue.identifier == "nameOfYourSegue") {
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```